# HTML: IE: Right padding in input text box

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, padding

Go to http://jsfiddle.net/srLQH/ and fill in the input text box in the "Result" view.

If you do this in FF, Chrome, and Safari, your text will stop 20px short of the right side.

In IE 7/8, the text does not stop 20px short--it goes all the way to the edge of the input box.

What's the deal with IE? How can I get the same padding effect in IE that all the other browsers give me?

Answer (score 7):

I have been looking for a way to solve this. A colleague found a solution and we tested it and it works perfectly. So the thing is to remove the `padding: right` and add a `border: 20px solid transparent`.

Comment: this works pretty well for ie8.  Modernizr adds the class "ie" to the HTML element which makes it easy to separate ie hacks. Use "box-sizing: border-box;" with it.

Comment: This works for other popular browsers as well. No need to make an exception for IE. By the way, left padding also needs to be treated this way.

Comment: mrust's answer is the -real- solution

Answer (score 5):

I've found one way of doing it, but its not pretty.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrytorba/dZyzr/162/

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
input {
  border: none;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px #aaa inset;
}
.spacer{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->


<span class='wrapper'>
    <input type='text' />
    <span class='spacer'></span>
</span>​
```

Comment: mrust's answer is the -real- solution

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but after a lot of searching, I found a solution that works.

You can add the "padding" back to IE by adding margins on the value using the following.

**default input padding**

```
    input[type="text"]{
        padding-left:17px;
        padding-right:17px;
    }
```

**padding for IE inputs**

```
    input[type="text"]::-ms-value {
        margin-left:17px;
        margin-right:17px;
    }
```

**but then you'll need remove the padding for IE 10+ (so it doesn't use both) which you can do with this media query.**

```
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        input[type="text"] {
            padding-left:0;
            padding-right:0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Damn this is clever. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if IE **is** applying the CSS, just not until the very end of the line. That is, the padding is influenced by the value, rather than the value influenced by the padding.

When setting the padding to 20px all the way around with a default value longer than the default width, you can scroll to the end and see the padding. http://jsfiddle.net/dZyzr/

You're going to have to come up with some visual trick, or just use a different style sheet for IE.

Comment: mrust's answer is the -real- solution

Answer (score 2):

Just chuck it in another element which does do padding in IE, such as a div. Then you don't need to worry about ugly hacks invalidating your css stylesheet. Remember to remove the padding from the input so it doesn't annoy other browsers. This is also the only way to give a text box a background image which doesn't scroll with the text in IE.

Comment: mrust's answer is the -real- solution

Comment: @Wouter All of the answers were fine when the question was asked in 2010, no need to downvote everyone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down : "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter ... an answer that is clearly ... incorrect." In light of the correct answer, all others are clearly incorrect imho. I understand this was not the case in 2010, but I don't see how that's relevant today. Nothing personal ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is an older question, but I fixed this in IE10 by following this:

How to fix this it For IE-10 :

```
::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```

Or for a specific input :

```
.anyinput::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

See more information here:
http://sarveshkushwaha.blogspot.com/2014/06/ie-right-align-text-input-issue.html

Comment: Just used this for a Kendo MaskedTextBox, worked perfectly when none of the other answers did/were appropriate. Thanks :-)

Comment: This was the real cause of the problem, and solution. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Try this ie hacks**

```
input{
 padding-right : 20px /* all browsers, of course */  
 padding-right : 20px\9; /* IE8 and below */  
 *padding-right : 20px; /* IE7 and below */  
 _padding-right : 20px; /* IE6 */  
}
```

***demo***

http://jsfiddle.net/srLQH/2/

***Tips***

padding dont work well with html form element ie input textarea like that 
try changing it to ***margin***

```
input{
 margin-right : 20px /* all browsers, of course */  
 margin-right : 20px\9; /* IE8 and below */  
 *margin-right : 20px; /* IE7 and below */  
 _margin-right : 20px; /* IE6 */  
}
```

since in jsfiddle , you have single element, why dont you try

**margin-left instead of margin-right**

Comment: Please check your work before you submit your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use css property **text-indent** for this element:

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cp68N/1/):

```
<input style="text-indent:15px" name="" type="text" value="test testtesttesttesttesttest" />
```

Comment: How come this didn't get upvoted?! omg Is the site broken. I guess it's cause they were asking for left padding but I found this useful.:)

Comment: Would have been nice to see a more effective solution