# Input tag padding-left issue in ie browsers

Tags: css, input

Please have a look on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/URBfj/

i have given padding-left to input tag and now when i am scrolling text in input tag its working fine bt in ie its not working fine.Ie not taking padding.

Comment: scroll the text from left aarrow key

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML: IE: Right padding in input text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765411/html-ie-right-padding-in-input-text-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See workaround on exact same question (though right instead of left side) [HTML: IE: Right padding in input text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765411/html-ie-right-padding-in-input-text-box)

Comment: OT question: How much rep do you need for that? Is that the same as if I flag the question as a duplicate?

Comment: You need 3000 http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions I assume it's the same as flag, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property **text-indent** for this element:

For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cp68N/1/):

```
<input style="text-indent:15px" name="" type="text" value="test testtesttesttesttesttest" />
```